Google's Meeting API does not seem to work for server to server calls
I am trying to fetch details and artifacts from the google meet recording by using the recently released Google Meet APIs. I want to make a server to server API call, so have created a service account with access to Google Meet APIs.
I have also enabled Google Meet API in the console.
My approach:
from google.oauth2 import service_account
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    filename='ultra-might-424911-b1-9f5cf95d5846.json',
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meet.recordings.readonly"]  # Add the required scope
)
client = meet_v2.ConferenceRecordsServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
request = meet_v2.GetRecordingRequest(name="xxx-xxxx-xxx")
response = client.get_recording(request=request)
print(response)

Scope value is coming from https://developers.google.com/meet/api/guides/overview#auth
(But these scopes are not present in https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes )
This fails with:
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Timeout of 60.0s exceeded, last exception: 503 Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: ('invalid_scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meet.recordings.readonly is not a valid audience string.', {'error': 'invalid_scope', 'error_description': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meet.recordings.readonly is not a valid audience string.'})

I have also tried this approach https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth
But this fails with message:
"Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project."

At this point, I have spent several hours and unsure how to get past this. Looking for any help or suggestion.

if i am not mistaken you are using Method: conferenceRecords.get
If you check the docs it tells you what scope you need which is one of these

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.created
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/meetings.space.readonly

service account
You appear to be using a service account.  You may want to also double check that you have configured the service account correctly in your google workspace domain Service account credentials

Thank you, I was looking to get transcripts, so did mix up the scopes.
After doing this, I am facing another error, even though I am passing correct conference id ...as "conferenceRecords/" as 'name' for GetRecordingRequest , so trying to figure that out currently:
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid resource name [field_violations {
  field: "name"
  description: "Invalid resource name"
}
]


Btw, the scopes that the you have referenced (and the ones referenced in google doc) does not exist anymore apparently. If you go the link, it says:
You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API.


the documentation is generated from the discovery doc.  it should be corect
